# Swift 3: Can you save the position of a cropped image and access it later when the full image is displayed?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

**Language:** Swift 3

**Task:** Allow users to crop their profile image on upload

**Question:** Initially I was going to try and figure out to save the cropped image and the full image to my server because I need both, then came up with the question... Is there a way to save the cropped **position** of the full image to my mysql database(php) then access it when I need to display the cropped image?

**I'm using**

```
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

**To allow the users to crop photo**

---

```
   let chooseAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Image", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
       if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) {
           self.imagePicker.delegate = self
           self.imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
           self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
           self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) }
   })

   let takeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Image", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
       if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
           self.imagePicker.delegate = self
           self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
           self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
           self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) }
   })

   let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })
   optionMenu.addAction(chooseAction)
   optionMenu.addAction(takeAction)
   optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
   self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

EDIT

[image]

1. I am saving the full image to server
2. I need the simplest way to get the cropped square position if possible then store the position in a variable (I will store this on my server)
3. On certain views when the image is displayed I only want to show the cropped part of the full image. I will retrieve the saved cropped position set on upload then only show that part of the image.

Comment: You mean like instead of sending cropped image you would send original image plus some crop rect, right? It should be easy enough. But I would avoid using UIImagePickerController for that, rather use a scroll view. I think you have quite a few samples on web that mimic cropping for you. Maybe check out one or two and come back with a more specific issue if you have one.

Comment: I mean is there a way to store what area of the original photo was cropped on image upload then when the image is displayed only show the cropped area? This info will need to be stored in my database because other users will need to see the cropped image. Everything on the image upload is fine this is my only problem.

Comment: I think the answer I posted could be your solution. But I have to note that this might be a little bit of a privacy issue. You imply to user that he is giving you only the cropped part of his image while you receive a whole thing. And as you mentioned you also give the whole thing to all users that need to see this cropped image. So if you as a user see my cropped image you could access data on your own phone and retrieve my none-cropped image which may have some cool stuff on it.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try this out since there are a few issues that can occur doing this. I made this example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrollViewPanel: HitForwardingView = HitForwardingView()
    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    private var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollViewPanel.frame = view.bounds
        scrollViewPanel.listenerView = scrollView
        view.addSubview(scrollViewPanel)

        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
        scrollView.center = CGPoint(x: scrollViewPanel.bounds.midX, y: scrollViewPanel.bounds.midY)
        scrollViewPanel.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0

        if let image = UIImage(named: "testImage") {
            setupWithImage(image)
            scrollToCenter()
        }

        // Just some masking to make things look nicer
        scrollViewPanel.addSubview({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: scrollViewPanel.bounds.width, height: scrollView.frame.minY))
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
            return view
        }())
        scrollViewPanel.addSubview({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: scrollView.frame.minY, width: scrollView.frame.minX, height: scrollView.frame.height))
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
            return view
        }())
        scrollViewPanel.addSubview({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.maxX, y: scrollView.frame.minY, width: scrollViewPanel.frame.width - scrollView.frame.maxX, height: scrollView.frame.height))
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
            return view
        }())
        scrollViewPanel.addSubview({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: scrollView.frame.maxY, width: scrollViewPanel.bounds.width, height: scrollViewPanel.frame.height - scrollView.frame.maxY))
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
            return view
        }())

        // Add a trigger to show crop
        view.addGestureRecognizer({
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(debugSnapshot))
            recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            return recognizer
        }())
    }

    @objc private func debugSnapshot() {
        // Going to use relative coordinates depending on the original image. The result should be a frame normalized depending on original:
        // x=0 is left-most
        // x=1 is right-most
        // y=0 is top-most
        // y=1 is bottom-most

        let convertedScrollViewFrame = scrollView.convert(scrollView.bounds, to: scrollViewPanel)
        let convertedImageViewFrame = imageView.convert(imageView.bounds, to: scrollViewPanel)

        var frame = convertedScrollViewFrame
        frame.origin.x -= convertedImageViewFrame.origin.x
        frame.origin.y -= convertedImageViewFrame.origin.y
        frame.origin.x /= convertedImageViewFrame.width
        frame.origin.y /= convertedImageViewFrame.height
        frame.size.width /= convertedImageViewFrame.width
        frame.size.height /= convertedImageViewFrame.height

        print(frame)

        // Do a reconstruction
        let previewPanelView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        previewPanelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        previewPanelView.addSubview({
            let panel = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0))
            panel.center = CGPoint(x: previewPanelView.bounds.midX, y: previewPanelView.bounds.midY)
            panel.clipsToBounds = true

            let imageView = UIImageView(image: self.imageView.image)
            // Frame now relative to where we display it (panel)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: -frame.origin.x * panel.bounds.width / frame.size.width,
                                     y: -frame.origin.y * panel.bounds.height / frame.size.height,
                                     width: panel.bounds.width / frame.size.width,
                                     height: panel.bounds.height / frame.size.height)
            panel.addSubview(imageView)


            return panel
        }())

        view.addSubview(previewPanelView)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            previewPanelView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    private func setupWithImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
    }

    private func scrollToCenter() {
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width*0.5 - scrollView.bounds.size.width*0.5,
                                           y: scrollView.contentSize.height*0.5 - scrollView.bounds.size.height*0.5)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

}

private extension ViewController {

    class HitForwardingView: UIView {

        weak var listenerView: UIView?

        override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
            let original = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
            if (original == self || original == nil) && self.bounds.contains(point) {
                return listenerView
            } else {
                return original
            }
        }

    }

}
```

To make it work you can simply create a new project and copy this code into your `ViewController`. You need a test image as well named "testImage". You can scroll your image around, zoom it in or out. If you double-tap a new overlay will appear which should show a cropped image.

**Explanations:**

1. The whole view controller is done in code just to make it easier to explain. In reality all the views would be done in storyboard with constraints.
2. Because we use a "small" scroll view we need to forward touch events to the scroll view even when you drag outside of it. To do so `HitForwardingView` is introduced. Basically it is collecting events and forwarding them to the scroll view.
3. Both "position" construction and deconstruction is demonstrated in `debugSnapshot`. To your backend you would send data from received `frame` in this method. You would then later use this same frame from backend to position image correctly to mimic cropped image.

I hope the rest is pretty much self-explanatory from the code. If there are any questions about it please go ahead.